# Mysql - select all columns of a single row with its values and column comments

Tags: mysql

Here is the query to get all columns of a single row

```
$STH = $DBH->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Settings"); 
$STH->execute();
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $str = '';
    while ($row = $STH->fetch()) 
    {
         foreach($row as $key => $value) 
         {
            $str .= '<div>'.$key.' => '.$value.'</div>';
         }
    }
```

and this one is to get extended information of the column (including `comment`)

```
$STH = $DBH->db->prepare("SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM Settings");
$STH->execute();
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

\* the same php code *\
```

can I combine these two SQL queries to get the following data simultaniously

```
`FieldName`, `FieldValue`, `CommentValueOfColumn`
```

'
'
'

example of Settings table

```
 Columns ->  | PrintImage  |   SettMinus |  HasChat  . . .
             --------------------------------------------
 Values ->          0                1          1    . . .
```

and there is additional data `Comment` of the column.
So I want to select data:

```
 PrintImage,  0 , Comment of PrintImage;
 SettMinus,   1 , Comment of SettMinus;
 HasChat,     1 , Comment of HasChat;
 .....................................
 and so on.
```

Comment: please show us sample values of settings table and result you want.

Comment: âńōŋŷXmoůŜ, see the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the column name, values of the columns and the comments. However, you can use php to get the values which is 
        **VALUEARRAY[ORDINAL_POSITION]**
You also need to copy/paste the rest of the column names after concat_ws.

Again, I cannot do everything in mysql so it needs help from PHPcodes to get the exact value from the array.

```
SELECT s.COLUMN_NAME, 
      s.ORDINAL_POSITION,
      t.valuearray,
      s.COLUMN_COMMENT
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns s
cross join (select concat_ws(",", PrintImage, 
SettMinus,HasChat) as valuearray from settings) t
where s.TABLE_NAME='Settings';

 sample  result :
 COLUMN_NAME    ORDINAL_POSITION    valuearray  COLUMN_COMMENT
 PrintImage     1                   0,1,1       commenttest
 SettMinus      2                   0,1,1       comments too
 HasChat        3                   0,1,1       3rd comment
```